# ASP.Net incremental page load call Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using the incremental page load pattern found [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax/how-do-i-implement-the-incremental-page-display-pattern-using-http-get-and-post).

I have a primary page that loads and displays a spinning wheel indicator, and calls another secondary page. That page displays HTML in the primary page just fine. However, I need a piece of javascript to run that is generated by the secondary page via `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(blah, blah);`.

I see the script manager-generated script at the bottom of the HTML injected by the secondary page, but it doesn't execute. When I make a request to the secondary page directly, the Javascript runs just fine. I've even tried wrapping the injected script in a function and calling that function from the primary page but the primary page says the function is undefined.

Edit:  here's the primary page code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var slat;
    var slong;  
    function check() {           
        if (navigator.geolocation) {                
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {                    
                // PageMethods.SetSession(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                slat = position.coords.latitude;
                slong = position.coords.longitude;
               callEventsService(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            });
        }
   }
   function callEventsService(lat, slong) {
       var progress = $get('progress');
       progress.style.display = '';       
       PageMethods.SetSession(lat, slong, eventsCallback);
   }
   function eventsCallback(result) {
       var progress = $get('progress');
       progress.style.display = 'none';
       GetWebRequest('IncrementalEvent.aspx')
   }    
    function GetWebRequest(getPage) {           
        var wRequest = new Sys.Net.WebRequest();
        wRequest.set_url(getPage);
        wRequest.set_httpVerb("GET");
        wRequest.set_userContext("user's context");
        wRequest.add_completed(OnWebRequestCompleted)
        wRequest.invoke();
    }
    function OnWebRequestCompleted(executor, eventArgs) {
        if (executor.get_responseAvailable()) {
            var grid = document.getElementById("grid");
            grid.innerHTML += executor.get_responseData();
             //calldisplaymap();  <-- DOESNT WORK, Function not  defined        
        }
        else {
            if (executor.get_timedOut()) {
                alert("Timed Out");
            }
            else {
                if (executor.get_aborted())
                    alert("Aborted");
            }
        }
    }        
</script>
```

Here's the secondary page load

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<GenericEvent> ge = (List<GenericEvent>)Session["publicevents"];
    lvevents.DataSource = ge;
    lvevents.DataBind();
    ExtractEventsToMap(ge);      
} 
   protected void ExtractEventsToMap(List<GenericEvent> lEvents)
{
    ...........<stuff>........
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "PointArrays", sb.ToString(), true);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "showmap", "function calldisplaymap(){displaymap(" + Session["lat"].ToString() + "," + Session["long"].ToString() + ")};", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(blah, blah)` subscribe event `$(document).ready()`, so it will not works in your case (when your second view loading, document allready ready). You should call htat piece of Javascript on success in ajax call that loads your second view.

**Update**

Try to add js function calldisplaymap() to aspx page instead registering it in codebehind. And use:
secondary page (aspx):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calldisplaymap() {
        displaymap(<%: Session["lat"].ToString()%>, <%:Session["long"].ToString()%>);
    };
</script>
```

primary page

```
function OnWebRequestCompleted(executor, eventArgs) {
        if (executor.get_responseAvailable()) {
            var grid = document.getElementById("grid");
            grid.innerHTML += executor.get_responseData();
            calldisplaymap();  //i hope, it will work.     
        }
        else {
            if (executor.get_timedOut()) {
                alert("Timed Out");
            }
            else {
                if (executor.get_aborted())
                    alert("Aborted");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, would you have an exapmle?

Comment: I have to register it from the code behind so it gets the lat long from the session

Comment: You can get it from session in aspx page too:

Comment: function calldisplaymap() {
            displaymap(<%: Session["lat"].ToString()%>, <%:Session["long"].ToString()%>);
        };

Comment: yeah, calldisplaymap is not defined